# Sculpt Mode Not Working

Tags: sculpt

Whenever I try to use the cloth sculpt tool, it shows up as red. The other sculpt tools don do this, but they just have no effect on anything. How do I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The red line is to remind you the radius of the *Simulation Limit*, which is not the same as the brush *Size*. The *Size* will determine the size of the brush, the *Simulation Limit* will determine the area where you can sculpt, the brush won't be able to sculpt beyond this limit. Before you sculpt this area will be a grey line, as soon as you left click, meaning you begin to sculpt, it will be this red line, and you can't change its position until you left click again.

As for the fact that you don't see any effect, its because this brush is a bit painful in default *Deformation > Drag* mode, first make sure that you have topology, then increase the *Strength* (up to 1 for example), left click on the part where you want to sculpt and shake the brush to get some folds (you can also decrease the *Cloth Mass* value to get more effects):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it